# Reporte sencillo en ReportViewer C#, añadir campos de 2 DataSets distintos

Tags: c#, reportviewer, dataset, ssrs, rdlc

estoy haciendo una aplicación de WindowsForm y necesito agregarle un **reporte sencillo**, es solo listar los datos que me devuelve una consulta, son datos de 2 tablas que están unidas por una llave foránea. 
El problema es que **a la tabla en el rdlc solo le puedo agregar campos del DataSet1, y necesito además el campo categoría del Dataset2**, cuando lo voy a agregar me sale el error que se ve en la foto...¿Cómo puedo resolver ese problema?
Agradezco mucho su colaboración[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes usar la función Lookup en una expresión

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ingresas el id de las dos tablas que se relacionan y la categoría

```
=Lookup(Fields!IdTabla1.Value,Fields!IdTabla2.Value,Fields!Categoria.Value, "DataSet2")
```

Comment: hola @Jefferson Cuji muchas gracias por tu respuesta... ¿Me podrías aclarar la nueva duda que tengo?
Muchas gracias